# Why does ~n give -(n+1)?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I wanted to test what happens when I write this code. I can not explain the following case:

Input: 5
Output: -6

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int lastBit(int n){   return ~(n); }

int main() {   std::cout << lastBit(5); }
```

Comment: Because that the definition of `~` (on a twos complement machine), what were you expecting instead?

Comment: Twos compliment - it is how many modern systems represent negative numbers. Play around online with a twos compliment calculator and look at the bit patterns

Comment: Because in two's complement arithmetic a - b = a + ~b + 1.

Comment: Here is a nice article on this subject: https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~tomf/notes/cps104/twoscomp.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Computers express negative numbers in quite a specific way. Values are always stored as series of bits and there is no way of introducing negative sign, so this has to be solved differently: one of bits plays role of a negative sign.

But this is not all - the system must be designed to handle maths properly (and ideally, the same way as for positive numbers).

So for instance `0 == 0b00000000`. If you subtract 1 from 0, you get -1, but from the binary perspective, due to "binary underflow", `0b00000000 - 0b00000001 == 0b11111111`, hence `0b11111111 == -1`.

If you then subtract 1 from -1, you get `0b11111111 - 0b00000001 == 0b11111110 == -2`. But `2 == 0b00000010`, which shows, why `-2 != ~2` (and the same rule applies to next values).

---

The very short, but maybe more intuitive answer might be: "-5 != ~5, because there is only one zero binarily (eg. 0 == -0), so there is always one more negative value than positive ones"

Answer (score 2):

Not on all systems but on systems that use complement of two for signed values. By definition there, the binary representation of negative `X = -n`, where `n` is a positive integer, is `~n + 1`, which allows signed and unsigned addition operations to be same.

Until C++20 result of `~(n)` for signed negative `n` here would be undefined, because it depends on platform and compiler. In C++20 it's required to behave as if complement of two is used.

Comment: -n = (~n +1) and not (~n - 1)

Comment: @StPiere typodaemons got me

Comment: Got it ! Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

I found out the following

5 = 0101
Therefore, ~(5) = 1010

1. The 1 at the most significant bit denotes negativee (-)
2. 010 = 6

Therefore, output is -6
Since this is a 2's complement machine

Comment: Sorry, binary `010` is 2 but not 6. I guess you didn't really get yet how [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) works, did you?